# Jumping with CharacterController doesnt work?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am very new to coding and i am trying to make a FPS, but i can't get the jumping mechanic to work. I am following a tutorial of Brackeys : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc

I have tried changing the standard jumping bind, i have tried using GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) instead of using GetButtonDown("Jump") , but nothing seems to work. Anybody knows how to fix this? I love you. Have been struggling for 16 hours now...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playermm : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
                }
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I recommend.

Type in this command at the end:

```
Debug.Log(isGrounded);
```

It should print true if the character is on the ground. If it prints true, then the error is with your velocity and moving the character or square root expression.

If it prints false, then the problem is with your ground check. you should check the position of 'groundCheck', if it is at the bottom of the charcter, then that is okay. Next, check the 'groundDistance', if the value is about 0.5, it should be okay. Then check the groundMask. If the groundMask is the same mask that the ground is applied to, then that is fine. If it returned true, then one of these is wrong.
Links for extra help:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html

Write back to me.